# Can I edit the print output of GCC in linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, terminal, edit, gcc-warning

I want the error massages print in a different color to terminal, is it possible and how?

I want to print the word 'ERROR' in red and 'warning' in yellow.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [colorgcc](http://schlueters.de/colorgcc.html) for that.

Answer (score 1):

See also:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_%28Unix%29#Variants

Answer (score 0):

if you like Ruby there is **[GilCC](http://www.onlysolutionssoftware.com/gilcc/)**! It is very easy to install and use. Unlike Perl based scripts **GilCC** has statistics such as # of warnings and error and compile time. You don't have to mess with .bash files and it is cross platform as long as you can run Ruby on your machine. Since it is Ruby you can make it do different things such as trigger test automation, unit test or program external hardware.

Here is the link to the download page: http://www.onlysolutionssoftware.com/gilcc/